# Loop through multiple different sized python dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am inheriting the following two python dictionaries from another class

```
>>> print init_treats
{('001', 0): init_treat_001_0, ('001', 3): init_treat_001_3, ('001', 2): init_treat_001_2, ('002', 0): init_treat_002_0, ('002', 1): init_treat_002_1, ('002', 2): init_treat_002_2, ('002', 3): init_treat_002_3, ('001', 1): init_treat_001_1}

>>> print init_untreats
{'002': init_untreat_002, '001': init_untreat_001}
```

**How can I generate the following?**

```
init_treat_001_0 + init_treat_001_1 + init_treat_001_2 + init_treat_001_3 +
init_untreat_001 == 0


init_treat_002_0 + init_treat_002_1 + init_treat_002_2 + init_treat_002_3 + 
init_untreat_002 == 0
```

Comment: You mean you want to match up the `init_treats.keys()..[0]` (first element in tuple keys) with the keys in `init_untreats`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, in order to develop the equation below. It's an optimization problem that I'm trying to develop equations for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your `init_treats` keys:

```
treats = sorted(init_treats)
```

now you can use `itertools.groupby()` to group them on the first part of your key:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for untreat, group in groupby(sorted(init_treats), itemgetter(0)):
    # group is now a sorted iterator of keys with the same first value
    if init_untreat[untreat] + sum(map(init_treats.get, group)) == 0:
        # sum of init_treat_n_m + init_untreat_n is 0
```

Because this uses sorting, this is a O(NlogN) solution (N being the size of the `init_treats` dictionary)

You could use a dictionary for a O(N + K) solution (K being the size of the `init_untreats` dictionary):

```
sums = init_untreat.copy()
for untreat, id in init_treats:
    sums[untreat] += init_treats[untreat, id]

for untreat, total in sums.items():  # use sums.iteritems() in Python 2
    if total == 0:
        # sum of init_treat_n_m + init_untreat_n is 0
```

Because K is always smaller than N in your case, asymptotically speaking this is a O(N) algorithm, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In your second part, it seems that sums[untreats] (for n+1) is overriding the result of sums[untreats] for (n). Or am I looking at this wrong? When I step in and look at the result of what sums[treats] is doing step by step, I see that the final result is two equations. When I get out of the loop an return sums[treat] I get only one.

Comment: @dassouki: `sums` groups sums by `untreat` keys. So for all `(untreat, id)` keys in the `init_treats` dictionary, their values are summed together grouped on the `untreat` part of the key. If you have two distinct `untreat` keys, you get two sums in that dictionary.